# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_with_attr' Brownie

Tags: python, pytest, solidity, brownie

I was following the freecodecamp smart contract course, i was in lesson 6 brownie Fund me/
when i was setting up my test it showed me the next error:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\kopid\brownie_fund_me
plugins: eth-brownie-1.16.4, hypothesis-6.21.6, forked-1.3.0, xdist-1.34.0, web3-5.23.1
collected 2 items

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545'...

tests\test_fund_me.py .F                                                                                                                                [100%]

========================================================================== FAILURES ========================================================================== 
________________________________________________________________ test_only_owner_can_withdraw ________________________________________________________________ 

    def test_only_owner_can_withdraw():
        if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
            pytest.skip("only for local testing")
        fund_me = deploy_fund_me()
        bad_actor = accounts.add()
        with pytest.raises(exceptions.VirtualMachineError):
>           fund_me.withdraw({"from": bad_actor})

tests\test_fund_me.py:25:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  
..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py:1693: in __call__
    return self.transact(*args)
..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py:1566: in transact
    return tx["from"].transfer(
..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py:680: in transfer
    receipt._raise_if_reverted(exc)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  

self = <Transaction '0x63305841a2be302452e87ea2a87eba05918dc803a7be60da1c0ddaa29930f7a4'>, exc = None

    def _raise_if_reverted(self, exc: Any) -> None:
        if self.status or CONFIG.mode == "console":
            return
        if not web3.supports_traces:
            # if traces are not available, do not attempt to determine the revert reason
            raise exc or ValueError("Execution reverted")

        if self._dev_revert_msg is None:
            # no revert message and unable to check dev string - have to get trace
            self._expand_trace()
        if self.contract_address:
            source = ""
        elif CONFIG.argv["revert"]:
            source = self._traceback_string()
        else:
            source = self._error_string(1)
            contract = state._find_contract(self.receiver)
            if contract:
                marker = "//" if contract._build["language"] == "Solidity" else "#"
                line = self._traceback_string().split("\n")[-1]
                if marker + " dev: " in line:
                    self._dev_revert_msg = line[line.index(marker) + len(marker) : -5].strip()

>       raise exc._with_attr(
            source=source, revert_msg=self._revert_msg, dev_revert_msg=self._dev_revert_msg
        )
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_with_attr'

..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\brownie\network\transaction.py:420: AttributeError
-------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
the active network is: development
deploying Mocks....
Mocks are now Deployed
Contract deployed to 0xe0aA552A10d7EC8760Fc6c246D391E698a82dDf9
mnemonic: 'first rather school desert dish hole bar can wagon dinner black abuse'
================================================================== short test summary info =================================================================== 
FAILED tests/test_fund_me.py::test_only_owner_can_withdraw - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_with_attr'
================================================================ 1 failed, 1 passed in 5.41s ================================================================= 
Terminating local RPC client...
```

any idea if the problem was with the code or is it something in brownie?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your `deploy_fund_me` method returns object correctly.
2. Maybe you're using Brownie with old versions (e.g. 1.16). You can
   upgrade to latest version (currently 1.18.1). One of solutions to upgrade is following steps:

   2.1. Run `pip uninstall eth-brownie`

   2.2. Clone brownie from `https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.git`

   2.3. Go to cloned folder, run `$python setup.py install`

After checking the version of Brownie is upgrade, you can run the test again.